# How do I write this function of this class?

Tags: class

I'm a beginner in C++ so I'm not sure how to make the question more detail. I'm sorry.
So my professor gave me this header file and told me to write the function definition:

```
    class Move
    { private:
    double x;
    double y;
    public:
    Move( double a = 0, double b = 0 ); // sets x_, y_ to a, b

    void showmove(Move number) const; // shows current x_, y_ values

    // add : Move --> Move
    // to add x_ of input object to x_ of invoking object to get new x_,
    // to add y_ of input object to y_ of invoking object to get new y_,
    // to create new object initialized to new values and return it
    Move add( const Move &m ) const;

    void reset( double a = 0, double b = 0 ); // resets x, y to a, b
    };
```

I don't understand the function **Move add( const Move &m ) const;**. Usually an add function look like this **int add( int a, int b)** . So combine 2 inputs together to make 1 output. But the function Move add only has one input. I don't know how to write a definition for it. I asked my friends and we come up with something like A.add(B), but I'm not sure if it makes any sense.
Thank you for reading and sorry for my English

Answer (score 0):

The definition should be

```
Move add(const Move& m) {
  return Move(this->x+m.x, this->y+m.y);
}
```

It wants you to use m's attributes to get the results directly with only one parameter (reference to a Move object) instead of two  (coordinates) .

Indeed, to invoke this method :

```
Move A/*sthg*/;
Move B/*sthg*/;
Move C = A.add(B);
```

Comment: There&#39;s a constructor that takes `(double, double)` as its parameters, there shouldn&#39;t be an undefined reference :@. If you use an &quot;external definition&quot; (header for declaration, cpp for definition) you needa refer to the class(at the definition) like this : `Move Move::add/*etc... */`